# How to combine multiple column value as single column in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi I've a multiple column like,

```
Address1, Address2

value1,   value2
```

I need this single column name in address like below

```
Address

value1
value2
```

How can I do this using mysql query?

Please someone help me...

Comment: Can you comment on how or if you want the addresses sorted in the single column?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `UNION` of the two columns to get them into a single column:

```
SELECT Address1 AS Address
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Address2 AS Address
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: I've both column in same table, in that case how could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Union` for this like

```
Select Address1 as Address 
FROM Table 
UNION 
Select Address2 
FROM Table
```